# Float array resampling

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I want to "stretch" a one-dimensional float array into a bigger array.

```
//expected behaviour

float[] initialArray = {2.0, 6.5, 2.0}
float[] biggerArray = resample(initialArray, 7 /*new size*/)

//output: {2.0, 3.5, 5.0, 6.5, 5.0, 3.5, 2.0}
```

The new values should propobaly be calculated from linear interpolation of the previous array values but i can't figure out how to achieve that.

Any hint ?

Comment: You mean [Polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). It's pretty easy to program. I find [Newton interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) easiest to program (I actually programmed it once in a competition, didn't take more than ~15 minutes)

Comment: @amit: The interpolation in the example looks pretty much linear to me.

Comment: Check out this library http://www.mathdotnet.com/ 
I've been using this for resampling, normalizing and a lot of other things. Really nice, easy to use and the documentation is pretty through too.

Comment: @MOehm looks quadric to me, given the fact that there is a local maximum at x=2,y=6.5

Comment: @amit: I referred to the interpolation between the sampled points, which is linear. (I took the interpolation to be piecewise. In my opinion, there's no indication that OP wants a polynomial approximation of the data points.)

Comment: @DavidWatts I would have tried that if Mark Shevchenko's solution didn't work. The library looks good, plus it's mono compatible (which i'm using).

Comment: @Chapapa Yeah, it's definitely worth checking out. Made my life a hell of a lot easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets the length of a source array is `N`, and the length of a destination array is `M` where `N < M` and `N > 1`.

You can calculate the new index of the source `i`-th element by the formula:

```
j = i * (M - 1)/(N - 1);
```

When `i == 0` then `j == 0`; and when `i == N - 1` then `j == M - 1`. The external loop can looks like this:

```
float[] source = ...;
float[] destination = ...;

destination[0] = source[0];
for (int i = 1; i < source.Length; i++)
{
    int j = i * (destination.Length - 1)/(source.Length - 1);
    destination[j] = source[i];
    // interpolation
}
```

To interpolation you should calculate intermediate values for each pair `(source[i - 1], source[i])`. You'll need to store previous value of `j`:

```
destination[0] = source[0];
int jPrevious = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < source.Length; i++)
{
    int j = i * (destination.Length - 1)/(source.Length - 1);
    Interpolate(destination, jPrevious, j, source[i - 1], source[i]);

    jPrevious = j;
}

private static void Interpolate(float[] destination, int destFrom, int destTo, float valueFrom, float valueTo)
{
    int destLength = destTo - destFrom;
    float valueLength = valueTo - valueFrom;
    for (int i = 0; i <= destLength; i++)
        destination[destFrom + i] = valueFrom + (valueLength * i)/destLength;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one works for both if source size is larger than destination and vice versa.

```
    private double[] Resample(double[] source, int n)
    {
        //n destination length
        int m = source.Length; //source length
        double[] destination = new double[n];
        destination[0] = source[0];
        destination[n-1] = source[m-1];

        for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            double jd = ((double)i * (double)(m - 1) / (double)(n - 1));
            int j = (int)jd;
            destination[i] = source[j] + (source[j + 1] - source[j]) * (jd - (double)j);
        }
        return destination;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<float>`:

```
float[] initialArray = { 2.0f, 6.5f, 2.0f };
List<float> initialArrayTemp = ToListFloat(initialArray);

private List<float> ToListFloat(float[] array)
        {
            List<float> list = new List<float>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                list.Add(array[i]);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Now your array is a dynamic array and you can add your new nodes anywhere of your `Array` by using `Insert()` method.

As soon as you need a new static array, use below:

```
float[] newInitialArray = initialArrayTemp.ToArray();
```